# PHP MySQL Not inserting any data. No errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure why it's not inserting any data.
No errors are returned.

I'm new in the mysql scene so i might be doing something wrong..

Do you guys mind pointing me towards the right direction?

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdatabase");

    if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


else if ($command == 'create-key'){

  $keys = $_GET['nkey'];

    if (empty($_GET['nkey'])){
      print('Error: No key specified to create!');
      die();
    }

    print ('Key '. $_GET['nkey'] .' has been created.');

    $sql = ("INSERT INTO `keys` (`key`, `status`) VALUES ('. $keys .', 0)");

}
```

SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE `keys` (
  `key` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: `VALUES ('. $keys .', 0)` that is where your error is at

Comment: I've been thinking of this as well.
But can't figure out how to write this instead?

Comment: Look al the colors in your post. Your query is wrong. Change `'. $keys .'` to: `'". $keys ."'`.

Comment: For Execute Query you must have to execute that

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `()`

Change Query From

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `keys` (`key`, `status`) VALUES ('. $keys .', 0)");
```

To

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `keys` (`key`, `status`) VALUES ('$keys', 0)";
```

And then Execute this Query

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need this on top of your script to see PHP errors:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
```

To help you with your error, have a look at your query.

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `keys` (`key`, `status`) VALUES ('. $keys .', 0)");
```

While this is should insert `. $keys .` in your table, please try:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `keys` (`key`, `status`) VALUES ('". $keys ."', 0)");
```